# Unable to update xml file using xmlstarlet with xml tag attribute

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

I am unable to update following xml file due to tag attribute, xmlns (namespace)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<advertiserFeatures
xmlns:doc="http://api.homeaway.com/service/v1"
xmlns="http://api.homeaway.com/domain/v0" etag="33054400302" url="/advertisers/0024/e74510aa-d4f0-4509-8c48-7c101e6f021c/features">
<parentEntity href="/advertisers/0024/e74510aa-d4f0-4509-8c48-7c101e6f021c" rel="parentEntity"/>
<advertiseVasCart>true</advertiseVasCart>
<agentAssistedCheckout>true</agentAssistedCheckout>
<dcfEnabled>false</dcfEnabled>
<enhancedDistribution>false</enhancedDistribution>
<inserted>2016-02-12T15:38:58.977Z</inserted>
<travelerFeeEnabled>true</travelerFeeEnabled>
<updated>2016-02-12T15:38:58.977Z</updated>
```

I can update with following command if I remove that attribute

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "/advertiserFeatures/advertiseVasCart" -v "false" advertiserFeatures.xml > advertiserFeatures1.xml
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind a prefix to the default namespace URI, and then use that prefix in your XPath to address elements in the corresponding namespace :

```
xmlstarlet ed -N x="http://api.homeaway.com/domain/v0" \
    -u "/x:advertiserFeatures/x:advertiseVasCart" \
    -v "false" advertiserFeatures.xml > advertiserFeatures1.xml
```

For further reading : [xmlstarlet documentation on *'Namespaces and default namespace'*](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05s01.html)